# Can superset support real-time dashboards?

Tags: apache-superset

We have a need to build a dashboard on Superset (sourcing data from Druid). I am a new user for superset and I maybe missing something. How can I make my charts on a dashboard in superset be a moving window? For example, I need my dashboard refresh every 1 min, with last 30 mins data.

Does superset support this?

Comment: I tried using now-1:now (for last 1 hr) but don't see it working

Answer (score 6):

I assume that you have data in Druid or database such as Postgres and you already have attached it to Superset as source/table.

Create your chart (time granularity: 1 minute, time range: Last 1 hour) and add it to a new dashboard. Then you should be able to set auto refresh interval (every 30 seconds) on that dashboard ->

[image]

That is pretty simple and not a permanent solution but this works for sure. 
I am using it.

Once an auto-refresh value has been set, it can also be customized under `Edit Dashboard Metadata` -> `JSON Metadata`

Comment: What if you aren't using Druid? I have a postgres database and I do not see this auto refresh interval option. The only option I have is "force refresh dashboard". Do i need to add some configuration?

Comment: When doing this, it always fetches data with interval relative to midnight:   "intervals": "2019-06-01T23:00:00+00:00/2019-06-02T00:00:00+00:00",
this is even my origin is:     "origin": "2019-06-02T14:04:23",

Comment: I'm also trying this. Using the "Big Number with Trendline" chart. There is no option for "Last hour" in the time range (shortest is "Last Day"). With "Last Day", it fetches data up until the end of the previous day, so this doesn't give a "live" graph.

Answer (score 0):

You set `Cache Timeout` value either on the chart, database or tables to your desired refresh interval. This will ensure cached data is cleared with the timeout period, which is the same as the `force refresh` button on the dashboard. Read more about superset caching [here](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/installation.html#caching). 
I think the cache period is in seconds.